# Query on java I/O byte stream class

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Below is the program which created separate byte streams for reading from and writing into same file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCopyNoBuffer{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        Long startTime, elapsedTime;

        //String inFileStr = "C:\\project\\books\\java-Preparation\\main_docs\\practice.jpg";
        //String outFileStr = "C:\\project\\books\\java-Preparation\\main_docs\\practice_out.jpg";
        String fileStr = "C:\\project\\books\\java-Preparation\\main_docs\\practice.jpg";

        File file = new File(fileStr);
        System.out.println("File size before - r/w is: " + file.length() + " bytes");
        try{
            in = new FileInputStream(fileStr);
            out = new FileOutputStream(fileStr);

            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            int byteRead;

            while((byteRead = in.read()) != -1){
                out.write(byteRead);
            }

            elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            System.out.println("Elapsed Time is: " + (elapsedTime/1000000.0) + " msec");
            System.out.println("File size after - r/w is: " + file.length() + " bytes");

        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if(in != null){
                    in.close();
                }
                if(out != null){
                    out.close();
                }
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Below is the observation:

```
File size before - r/w is: 1115512 bytes
Elapsed Time is: 0.040711 msec
File size after - r/w is: 0 bytes
```

I know that `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` are non-buffer byte stream I/O classes.

I expect that the file size to remain same after writing to same file.

What could be under-hood reason that file size goes to zero?

*Note : am learning java 1.6 I/O*

Answer (score 4):

> [...]for reading from and writing into same file.

**NEVER DO THAT. EVER**.

The results are unpredictable.

If you want to modify the contents of a file, write the new contents into a *new* file and then atomically rename to the old -- *after* you have ensured that the new content was successfully written.

Also, this is 2014, so unless you REALLY have to use Java 6, [use `java.nio.file` instead](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API), especially if you have to rename, since [`File` will leave you stranded more often than not](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks#Why_can.27t_I_rename_my_file.3F.3F).

Sample code with java.nio.file:

```
final Path toChange = Paths.get("pathtoyourfilehere");
final Path dir = toChange.getParent();
final Path tmpfile = Files.createTempFile(dir, "foo", "bar");

try (
    final InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(toChange);
    final InputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(tmpfile);
) {
    // Work with in and out
}

// Then move!
try {
    Files.move(tmpfile, toChange, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
        StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
} catch (AtomicMoveNotSupportedException ignored) {
    Files.move(tmpfile, toChange, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: i think C file I/O api read()/write() of `libC` library handle this situation. am i correct? `read()` api of `FileInputStream` is also native method, so it would call some C native code. am new to java, it will take more time to learn `java.nio` package

Comment: And? You said you "think" -- do you really want to take that risk? Believe me, do learn java.nio.file, it's worth the time. By the way, the tutorial I linked to is mine, so if you have questions on it, ping me. I'll fix any unclear points.

Answer (score 0):

You are using default constructor for FileOutputStream
Try using this:

```
out = new FileOutputStream(fileStr,true);
```

So that now your data will be appended instead of being overwritten.You can go through this:
[doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)